# Americans and other nationals who have died under U.N. command, broken down by conflict

Tags: united-nations

I'd like to know if there is any breakdown of the number of people, specifically by nation, who have died under U.N. command (whether as peacekeepers wearing the blue helmets, as diplomatic or service personnel, as U.S.military working under the umbrella of a U.N. response, etc.).

I know there was the Korean conflict and the first Iraq war which had U.N. sanction and whose casualty numbers should be easy to find, but I was wondering if there were a comprehensive list anywhere.

Comment: I would be surprised if anyone made such a list because it encompasses widely different things.

Comment: Even a subset of some kind would be helpful.

Comment: For peacekeeping missions, the UN publishes some statistics, including [fatalities by year, nationality, mission, etc.](http://www.un.org/en/peacekeeping/resources/statistics/fatalities.shtml).

Comment: Awesome. Great find. Feel free to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promoted from a comment: For peacekeeping missions, the UN publishes some statistics, including [fatalities by year, nationality, mission, etc.](http://www.un.org/en/peacekeeping/resources/statistics/fatalities.shtml). And here is a [blogpost from The Hindu](http://www.thehindu.com/opinion/blogs/blog-datadelve/article6547767.ece) commenting on these data.